# build.properties and build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

anyone can tell me the ant build (internal) procedure, and how build.properties info is used?

by the way, I am opening a project with build.properties -- but the projects I was working on did not seem to have such a file (newbie question) can someone give me an intro? is that an eclipse generated file?

Answer (score 4):

The build.property can override your properties in your build.xml without having to modify it.

[Building with Ant: Introduction](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/989631/Building-with-Ant-Introduction.htm) states :

> The  construct is usually used to include a file called build.properties. This is a convention used so that you can override default values for your local build environment, without having to modify build.xml (which may, after all, be a shared file, under version control). This means that build.properties should probably not be under version control (add it to .cvsignore under CVS).

---

**Resources :**

- [Evil Ant Build Properties](http://www.javaranch.com/ant/properties.jsp)
- [Building with Ant: Introduction](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/989631/Building-with-Ant-Introduction.htm)
- [vaanniala - Ant Properties File](http://www.vaannila.com/ant/ant-properties-file.html)

Comment: If you are using a PDE project instead of a plain Java project, then the build.properties file is used to configure the PDE generation of the build.xml script.  In this case it should be version controlled.

Comment: ... where PDE apparently means " Plug-in Development Environment", relating to Eclipse.